# How to perform a MySQL Dump to a remote datastore

Tags: mariadb, vmware, database-backups

I am trying to get the databases backed up from a local machine to a datastore. The local machine is a VM within VCenter and I need the DB to go onto one of it's datastores.

I know the command for MySQLDump is:

```
mysqldump -u (username) -p --all-databases > (backupfilename).sql.
```

What do I put in the second section to get it to connect and push the backup to the datastore as a file?

I tried the typical stuff you'd scp and rsync for but I'm not that versed in MariaDB, especially this version we have.

Answer (score 1):

If you know login credentials and hostname (and whatever extra arguments you need) to connect to remote instance, you may replace `> backupfilename.sql` with `| mysql -U user -P password -H host ....` to pipe mysqldump directly or even use `| tee somefile.sql | mysql ....` to also have a local dump.

Mariadb vs mysql is almost inerchangeable, but dont bet your life on this assumption - check the outcome.

Nb: if remote server is only listening locally and not available via internet, you may use ssh port forwarding/socket forwarding to connect.

Comment: I'm not like backing this up to another database, I'm trying to make a backup copy of it on a remote server. Would I still need a mysql login for the destination?

Comment: No. You may pipe to something like `| ssh user@host "cat > file.sql" ` in this case.

Comment: NB - for huge dumps this implies stable network. If your ssh disconnects - you will have incomplete dump. So if you can - do local dump + rsync/scp. The only situations when theese hacks with pipes make sense - when you need it fast, or when there is not enough space locally.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I did wind up doing a du check on the mysql folder where the databases are and it was small enough to do a local backup and I wound up doing the local and scp. I really appreciate your help!